# Android Slider - Max Value and Max Slide Value

Tags: android

Android Slider has a max value which applies to the entire slider. However, I need a way to have the max value and also a way to prevent the slider from going past another value. For instance, I want a slider that has a max value of 100 but (depending on other conditions) I want to prevent the user from sliding past 70.

Simple Slider.

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/sldOne"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Code

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sldOne);
seekBar.setMax(100);
```

I looked into onchange but that did seem to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `OnSeekBarChangeListener` to override changes past 70.

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // Prevent moving above 70
            if (progress > 70){
                seekBar.setProgress(70);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // Notification that the user has started a touch gesture.
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // Notification that the user has finished a touch gesture.
        }
    });
```

Comment: change to progress > 70 - otherwise it works decently well.